# push in array with auto-create in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, push

i want to know if it's possible to push in array with auto-creation of array if doesn't exist already, like in PHP:

```
$toto[] = 'titi';
```

if $toto is not already defined, it will create array and push 'titi' into. If already exist, it will just push.

in Ruby i have to do:

```
toto ||= []
toto.push('titi')
```

It's possible to do this in one line?

Because if i have an loop, it will test "||=" for nothing except the first time:

```
Person.all.each do |person|    
   toto ||= [] #with 1 billion of person, this line is useless 999 999 999 times...
   toto.push(person.name)
```

have you a better solution?

thx.

Comment: Why don't you put that line outside the loop?

Comment: @rohit89 you can put it as an answer

Comment: if i do that, and they are 0 Person, the array will exist [] instead of to be nil

Comment: @Matrix does that really hurt so much? `toto = [] unless Person.empty?`

Comment: if i test: "if toto", the result not the same. false positive if toto = []

Comment: yes we can, but it's boring to declare (with a test) the array, but ok, ruby is not php, no solution in short ^^

Comment: up me if my aswer is BEST. :)

Comment: check or up the helpful answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
toto = Person.all.reduce([]) do |arr, person|
  arr << person.name
end
```

or you could simply pluck the names if they come from the DB

```
toto = Person.pluck(:name) # SELECT `people.name` FROM `people`
```

Comment: Note: this only works because `Array#<<` returns `self`

Comment: What's the difference between `pluck` and `map` except the latter requires an extra pretzel?

Comment: @JanDvorak map `Person.all` will initialize entire DB rows as AR objects where `Person.pluck(:name)` does something like `SELECT people.name FROM people`

Comment: so, the difference is `pluck` acts before the database query takes place, and builds the query?

Comment: @JanDvorak yes - similar to `Person.count`

Answer (score 4):

In a single line it will be as:

```
toto = (toto || [] ) << 'titi'
```

and for `Person` name:

```
toto = (toto || [] ) << person.name
```

If you don't need to rewrite the `Array` do as follows:

```
( toto ||= [] ) << 'titi'
```

Comment: if you do that, you overwrite the array. sry i don't see your edit, but you write it in one line, but the test is alwais here...

Answer (score 3):

In this case I'd just go straight to [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
toto = Person.all.each_with_object([]) do |person, toto|
  toto.push(person.name)
end
```

Alternatively, you could just [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) it:

```
toto = Person.all.map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 2):

I will do as below :

```
toto = toto.to_a + Person.all.map(&:name)
```

Comment: Why the extra `toto.to_a` and concatenation?

Comment: @muistooshort in case `toto` was non-empty before the loop

Comment: @muistooshort Jan Dvorak is right.. But to consider this, if `toto` not exist, then to avoid error `no method`, I applied `nil#to_a` which will give `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

if $toto is not already defined, it will create array and push 'titi' into. If already exist, it will just push.

in Ruby i have to do:

toto ||= []
toto.push('titi')
It's possible to do this in one line?

Yes answer is:

```
toto ||= Array.new(1, 'titi')
```

Because if i have an loop, it will test "||=" for nothing except the first time:

```
Person.all.each do |person|    
  toto ||= [] #with 1 billion of person, this line is useless 999 999 999 times...
  toto.push(person.name)
end
```

have you a better solution?

you can use it simple with:

```
toto ||= Person.all.collect(&:name)
```